# Can RRule descirbe an event that occurs at two specific times each day?

Tags: rrule

Let's say I have an event that occurs at 7:00 and 2:00pm each day. The RRule would look like this:

```
FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=10,14
```

If I wanted an event that occurs at 10:00am and 2:**30**pm, I would *assume* it would look like this:

```
FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=10,14;BYMINUTE=0,30
```

But this doesn't seem to be correct. The spec says that "BYxxx rule parts for a period of time less than the frequency generally increase or expand the number of occurrences of the recurrence". Testing this at http://jkbrzt.github.io/rrule/ produces the following:

- Mon 10:00
- Mon 10:30
- Mon 14:00
- Mon 14:30
- Tue 10:00
- Tue 10:30
- Tue 14:00
- Tue 14:30

What I really want is this:

- Mon 10:00
- Mon 14:30
- Tue 10:00
- Tue 10:30
- Wed 10:00
- Wed 14:30
- Thu 10:00
- Thu 14:30

Comment: I don't think you can in one RRULE, but if you're working with icalendars (or vcalendars) you can simply add multiple RRULES in one component, so  
`RRULE;FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=10;BYMINUTE=0
RRULE';FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=14;BYMINUTE=30` 
would do what you want. Otherwise, I couldn't directly find anything in the RFC on how to do your specific case in a oneliner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out I could make this work using `BYSETPOS`:

```
FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=10,14;BYMINUTE=0,30;BYSETPOS=1,4
```

If you wanted 10:30am and 2:00pm, you'd use:

```
FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=10,14;BYMINUTE=30,0;BYSETPOS=2,3
```

The recurrence instances will be in chronological order, so, the order of `BYMINUTE` has no effect on `BYSETPOS`. To demonstrate, if we remove `BYSETPOS`, both of the above rules will yield the following instances for each day:

```
╔═══╦══════╦════════╗
║ P ║ Hour ║ Minute ║
╠═══╬══════╬════════╣
║ 1 ║   10 ║     00 ║
║ 2 ║   10 ║     30 ║
║ 3 ║   14 ║     00 ║
║ 4 ║   14 ║     30 ║
╚═══╩══════╩════════╝
```

So in the first case, we're selecting instances 1 and 4, and in the following case we're selecting instances 2 and 3.

Note that this only works if `DTSTART` uses the first `BYHOUR`/`BYMINUTE` values (10:00am in the above cases).

Comment: Think of it this way: the RRULE will generate multiple event instances. BYSETPOS will select specific instances from the set generated by the RRULE.

Answer (score 1):

While support for multiple RRULE was there in RFC2445, it has been removed from RFC5545 for lack of interoperability between calendar agents. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1

```
              ;
              ; The following is OPTIONAL,
              ; but SHOULD NOT occur more than once.
              ;
              rrule /
```

Similarly, anything that would involve BYHOUR/BYMINUTE is likely to have very poor interoperability (although those are still in the iCalendar spec).

In other words, it all depends what applications will consume those events. If you are in a closed environment where you control the clients, then you may want to go for the 2 RRULES described above.

If you do care about generic calendar clients, you are running a risk:

- most of the clients will not let you edit the event RRULEs fully,
- quite a few clients will misinterpret the rule when displaying the event.

As a workaround, you may want to create 2 events and link them with a related-to property (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.5 )